# have high/great hopes of/for somebody - which preposition should be used?

Tags: grammaticality

Which preposition should I use with have high/great hopes.... "for" or "of"? In many dictionaries more appropriate version is with "for" I guess, when we refer to somebody. But I've found  "of" in Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English 4th Edition. In newer versions there is no such an example. It's only with "for". I specifically refer to this example. Is it correct? Can I use "of" with somebody?
http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/hope_2

> have high/great hopes of
>   We have great hopes of her - she's very
>   talented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, there is an implied meaning

> We have great hopes **of her** ***(success)*** - she's very talented
>   We have great hopes **of our children's success**

However referring directly about to a person it is better to use **for**

> We have great hopes **for her**
>   We have great hopes **for our children**

Comment: Can I also use "for" in We have great hopes of our children's success. ?